# One layout on top of the another?

Tags: java, android, xml

I need one big image to take all the widht and about 80% of the height and I need a bunch of small image ot top of that big one. Both need to start in the top left corner. The big image will not be visible cause the small ones will cover it of course. Here's how small image should look like, and that's OK:

[image]

Beneath them I need one big image. I tried with two linear layouts but it did not work. These 36 small images are placed in 6 horisontal linear layouts. Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bIzlazCigle"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
        android:text="Izlaz"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bKonacnoCigle"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
        android:text="Konačno rešenje!"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView (or whatever, for background image) />

    <LinearLayout>  <-- this here is the XML you posted
        <LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton/>
            ...
        ...
     </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If the Background (as an `ImageView`) and the `LinearLayout` are at the same depth and both children of a `RelativeLayout`, they will stack on top of eachother.

You could replace `RelativeLayout` with `FrameLayout`, but don't because that `View` has more overhead for construction and you aren't drawing a `Fragment` so you don't need it.

Comment: OK, i've tried this, looks OK, but when I just to try set background to my imageView, it gets on top, I can't see my imageButtons any more. I need that imageView on botom.

Comment: It actually did not get on top of my buttons, it pushed my buttons down off the screen.

Comment: hmmm I took a look at the solution you posted, and if you replace it `FrameLayout` with `RelativeLayout` that looks correct to me-- I'm not at eclipse right now so go with the working solution!

Comment: Yes, it worked, but I have another problem now. But that's for another thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), replace the outer LinearLayout with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use Frame Layout -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

the way create the view you want is to create a layout (for example linear layout) containing the big image then adding it to the frame layout then create another layout (for example linear layout) that contain all the small image then adding it again to the frame layout so the layout with small images will be placed in front of the layout with big images

I hope this can answer your question, but if you have another question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the solution, if anyone needs it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSlika"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="398dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tesla" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIzlazCigle"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Izlaz"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bKonacnoCigle"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons_final"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Konačno rešenje!"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```